# Date parsing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, datetime, cross-browser, momentjs

I have dates of format : `Jul 2016` . I can parse it to unix epoch in Chrome using `Date.parse()` but it doesn't work in Firefox. Is there any way to make it work in Firefox ?

I decided to use momentJS library. It looks like that `moment(dateValue).unix()` must work which doesn't ! Is there any way to solve this issue without using RegEx and other hacky ways ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
moment(dateValue,'MMM YYYY').unix()
```